# Noneditable textbox but able to select text and process

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, textbox, wp7test

I want to display some text in text box and want to select some text from it and process it.But i don't want to edit the text box.How can i achieve this in wp7? Read only text box doesn't let you process the selected text.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "process" the selected text?

Comment: I want to do some manipulation on the user selected text from the textbox. For eg Translate the selected text into different language

Comment: So you're talking about `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`?

Comment: No am talking about  System.Windows.Controls.TextBox

Comment: Just that user should be able to select the text n not edit or delete using soft keyboard and i should be able to get the selected string

Answer (score 0):

Might not be an ideal solution but what about using a text block (per word) and adding a mouse enter event for each? Like that when they touch each word they want translated you can process each one individually? Not ideal if you have many words but for a few it could work.